# How to load a file in GT.M?

Tags: database

we tried loading a file in GT.M. we started off by invoking mupip and then load command. it read the file but shows an error. do we need to define a schema? if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to assist you if you post the error you see, and also what steps you have taken to troubleshoot it that may be suggested by the GT.M Messages and Recovery Procedures manual (go to http://fis-gtm.com and click on the User Documentation tab).

Answer (score 1):

It might also be clear if you clarify what you mean by "load a file". You could be talking about running a program (routine) that is stored as a host operating system file such as "myprogram.m",  or you could be talking about loading a file full of data stored in, perhaps a comma seperated value format, in a host operating system file such as "mydata.csv".

Also (admittedly unlikely) you could be talking about loading a VistA FileMan File, that is stored as a host operating system file formatted as a KIDS build such as in "package.kid" where the FileMan data dictionary (a form a schema) is stored in that KIDS format.